# Is it OK to translate "disable" as "deshabilitar" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

As a programmer, I'm quite used to the English term "disable" and its Spanish counterpart *"deshabilitar"*.

Alas, I recently discovered that, even though a quick Google search spews 3+ million results for the word, [the DLE does not recognize *"deshabilitar"*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=deshabilitar).

So what word should I use? Or should I just keep using it and hope for its inclusion in the DLE, given its wide acceptance?
Better yet, what words do *you* use for this concept, in the context of computing, software, etc.?

Comment: Creo que lo que la RAE reconoce es ["inhabilitar"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LbHds94)

Comment: +1 for the use of "alas".

Comment: Podrías usar *desactivar* en la mayoría de los casos, aún así como dice @CarlosAlejo no veo nada de malo en *deshabilitar* existiendo el verbo *habilitar* en castellano.

Comment: inabilitar **y** desabilitar: https://www.abc.es/tecnologia/informatica/software/abci-recomienda-deshabilitar-siri-asistente-apple-202004141136_noticia.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ya hemos visto en otras ocasiones que el hecho de que una palabra no venga en el diccionario no quiere decir que sea errónea, si las partes que la componen no lo son.

En este caso, *deshabilitar* va precedida de *[des-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CJuPwUn)*, que en español indica una inversión del significado de la palabra que le sigue. Por tanto, si *[habilitar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JvLO70G)* significa "hacer a algo apto para una determinada cosa", *deshabilitar* es lo opuesto: hacerlo no apto para esa cosa determinada.

Buscando en Twitter, vemos que la RAE ha defendido en varias ocasiones el uso de *deshabilitar*:

> «Editable» y «deshabilitar» son derivados correctamente formados y su empleo no es censurable. ([Enlace](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/605356938629660673).)
>
> Es un der. negativo de «habilitar» bien formado y difundido en informática; no se considera incorrecto. ([Enlace](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/704577381709828096).)
>
> «Deshabilitar» es un derivado negativo correcto de «habilitar», muy difundido en el ámbito informático. ([Enlace](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/614022556207722496).)

Comment: No sabía que "sancionar" equivaliera a "autorizar, aprobar". Una que he aprendido hoy. :-)

Comment: Misma etimología de la versión en inglés: _sanction_

Answer (score 5):

Yo usaría la palabra "desactivar" en lugar de "deshabilitar". Aunque la palabra "deshabilitar" es técnicamente correcta - yo siento que no concuerda con el significado que querés comunicar.

Lo más importante es que la palabra refleje la idea que querés comunicar.

Comment: Si le entiendo - va tomando una definicion como la palabrar "deactivate" en Ingles. Yo de todos modos iria con "desactivar" - esa es la palabra que usamos nosotros para referir a un boton o elemento en software que es bloqueado. Toma en cuenta que cada pais Latino Americano tiene su manera de decir ciertas cosas - para nosotros en Colombia "deshabilitar" refiere mas a la salud que a lo tecnologico

Comment: Desactivar no es lo mismo que deshabilitar. Un control de un formulario puede estar activado/desactivado Y habilitado/deshabilitado (que puedes o no activarlo/desactivarlo)

Answer (score 2):

Deshabilitar no, pero si [desactivar, desconectar, inhibir, inutilizar, invalidar](http://www.tugurium.com/gti/termino.php?Tr=disable)

Cuando se realiza la desconexión de un elemento del sistema podemos decir que se 'desactiva', se 'desconecta' o se 'inutiliza' o 'inhibe' su uso.

También, cuando se restringe el acceso a funciones de un sistema o programa (por ejemplo, una entrada del menú en la que no se puede pulsar) estamos 'inhibiendo', 'desactivando' o 'invalidando' su uso.

Estoy de acuerdo que podemos construir palabras usando las reglas del español, pero si ya existen términos que los describen ¿no sería mejor usarlos? IMHO

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73520/discussion-on-answer-by-jlprieto-is-it-ok-to-translate-disable-as-deshabilita).

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que deshabilitar se aplica a cosas, y que inhabilitar se aplica a personas. No parece bien decir que una persona está deshabilitada, mas bien una persona está inhabilitada. Tampoco suena bien decir que una computadora esta inhabilitada, una computadora esta deshabilitada.

El lenguage Ingles es muy pobre en ese sentido, se usa solo una palabra que es "disable" y lo aplican tanto para cosas como para personas. En particular me parece muy triste decir que una persona es "disable" como si fuerse una cosa o una maquina que no sirve mas.

Comment: En ingles usamos tambien deactivate, inactivate, neutralise, ... y no solo disable.

Comment: Según el DLE, "inhabilitar" también puede aplicarse a cosas en su segunda acepción. Creo que tú te quedas solo con la primera que es la más usada pero no la única. https://dle.rae.es/inhabilitar

Answer (score 0):

Un profesor experto en gramática me dijo que lo correcto era inhabilitar, pero dos españoles expertos en tecnología me dijeron que con deshabilitar no había problema, creo que se pueden usar intercambiablemente deshabilitar/desactivar la conexión, desactivar clips, el auto-panning, pero en otros casos usaría solamente deshabilitar, p.ej deshabilitar una función determinada de un software, o deshabilitar algo en una configuración del sistema(settings), deshabilitar el sleep(reposo), deshabilitar el logging(registro), deshabilitar ACPI en el arranque(boot), deshabilitar un programa en el arranque(startup) y más desactivar para un aparato o artefacto físico, como un equipo, máquina, pc o desactivar una bomba.

*y haz clic en el icono de "deshabilitar retweet,"*

*deshabilitar tales funciones de seguridad.*

*habilitar o deshabilitar estas funciones usando un simple comando*

*deshabilite el DVD en su máquina virtual.*

*deshabilitando la cuenta ROOT*

*desactive el audio de los clips*

*Esta opción desactiva la posibilidad de recordar contraseñas.*

*cualquier servidor DNS será desactivado durante la conexión*

*Desactivar la compartición de la carpeta deseleccionando*

También hay que considerar el aspecto regional, deshabilitar es muy usado y normal para mx y toda la. Tengo la certeza de que inhabilitar no es muy usado en cosas relacionadas con tecnología, jamás lo he escuchado ni tampoco lo he visto.